# should i ignore the "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency" error in this scenario

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, react-hooks, eslint

i'm new to using react and hooks.  I have a scenario that I'm coding where I load a list of employees depending on the viewmode state of my form... this is set based on a url parameter.  Anyways I only want to load the data (an array of employee objects) from a db when the viewmode changes.  Independently, I also have  sorting going on in my employee object array in memory when the user picks some sort options.

In my useEffect I load the data for a viewmode then sort it as per the current sort options (i know i could do this all in SQL but i'm doing it in javascript for now). At any time the user can change the sort order (without altering viewmode) and I just re-sort the data (without loading data from the db again, this is accomplished by createing a copy of the employee object array, sorting it and calling setState)  These scenarios are working fine except i'm getting the eslint error "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'sortEmployeesc'

I have tried moving the sort function (sortEmployeesc) into the useEffect, but then it tells me that I have a dependency on sortMode.sortby and sorMode.order.  The thing is i don't want to grab my SQL data again (via the useEffect) if they are just doing a sort, because i handle this in my event handler for my sort controls (where i call sort, then setState on the array). (so I dont' want this dependency to cause the useEffect to happen if its just the sort order changing).

I'm very new to REACT and Hooks so maybe i'm missing something obvious here...

```
function EmployeesPage(props) {
  const activeStyle = { color: "green" };
  //holds the array of employee objects
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);
  const [sortMode, setSortMode] = useState({
    sortBy: "LastName",
    order: "Ascending",
  });

  debugger;

  const viewmodein = props.match.params.viewmode;
  const viewmode = viewmodein !== undefined ? viewmodein : "nonarchived"; //sets default viewmode

  //creates a copy of the state employees array, sorts it and updates state
  function sortEmployees(updatedSortMode) {
    let copy = []
      .concat(employees)
      .sort(compareValues(updatedSortMode.sortBy, updatedSortMode.order));
    debugger;
    setEmployees(copy);
  }

   //given an array of employees, sorts it and updates state
  function sortEmployeesc(_employees) {
    _employees.sort(compareValues(sortMode.sortBy, sortMode.order));
    debugger;
    setEmployees(_employees);
  }

  //use effect that happens when viewmode changes (loads data from db)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (viewmode === "nonarchived")
      getNonArchivedSQLEmployees().then(_employees =>
        sortEmployeesc(_employees)
      );
    if (viewmode === "all")
      getAllSQLEmployees().then(_employees => sortEmployeesc(_employees));
    if (viewmode === "archive")
      getArchiveSQLEmployees().then(_employees => sortEmployeesc(_employees));
  }, [viewmode]);

  //change handler for sort controls 
  function handleChange(event) {
    const updatedSortMode = {
      ...sortMode,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    };
    debugger;
    //sets new sort mode, then sorts the employees array and updates the state of the employee object array
    setSortMode(updatedSortMode);
    sortEmployees(updatedSortMode);
  }
```